# Trigger getSignedUrl function in node back, pass to front

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-cloud-platform

TL;DR — how do I trigger a getSignedUrl function in my node backend from the React frontend, and return the result to the frontend?

NTL;RM — In my backend server.js file the below function generates a signed url from gcloud, but I'm not sure how to 1) trigger the function from the front end and 2) get the resultant signedUrl back to the front end where I'll use it to upload to gcloud directly from the browser.

**Backend:**

```
import express from 'express';
...
app.get('/api/gcloud', () => generateV4UploadSignedUrl().catch(console.error)); // I think this is wrong because the 

async function generateV4UploadSignedUrl() {
  const bucketName = 'my-gloud-bucket';
  const filename = uuidv4();
  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'write',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  };

  // Get a v4 signed URL for uploading file
  const [signedUrl] = await storage
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(filename)
    .getSignedUrl(options);
  console.log(signedUrl); // log out fine.
  return signedUrl;
}
```

**Frontend:**

```
  async function getUploadURL() {
    try {
      const { data } = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/gcloud');
      console.log(data.url); // data undefined
      return data.url;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've never seen NTL;RM, what does that stasnd for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endpoint does not return any response at the moment. You can send the URL in a JSON response.

```js
app.get('/upload-url', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = await generateV4UploadSignedUrl()
    res.json({ url })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: err.message })
  }
}
```

You can now send a request from the frontend (using your favorite library) to fetch the URL.

An example using [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios):

```js
async function getUploadURL() {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get('https://yourdomain.com/upload-url')
    return data.url
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Or if you're using `fetch`:

```js
async function getUploadURL() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://yourdomain.com/upload-url')
    const data = await response.json()
    return data.url
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get `res.json is not a function` in the try block of app.get. I tried passing res in `async (res) =>` but no luck. The value from  `generateV4UploadSignedUrl()` is not making it back to frontend.

Comment: @KirkRoss My bad. Just fixed the code to include `req` and `res` in the callback. The first argument in the callback is the `request` object. That's why your attempt didn't work.

Comment: if I console `data.url` before the return (after axios.get in frontend), I get `can't read property url of undefined`. Even if I `console.log(getUploadURL());` it's undefined. BUT... on the backend, the signedURL is being generated and I can log it in the backend. I'm using fetch btw, but I don't think that matters.

Comment: @KirkRoss Can you update your question with the `fetch` code?

Comment: @KirkRoss Just updated my answer to show how to use `fetch`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).